# Text format for badges

Tags: discussion, support, badges

I have found and read full [Edit help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) which is useful to edit/add the question or answer.

It looks so pretty for me and to all.

**My question is:** Is there any format to show the badge as it is visible on profile or badges list?

Example: For tag format, I used `[tag:tagname]` which gives the output like: [tagname](/questions/tagged/tagname).

But I have not found any such formatting option for badges which will give us the output like:

[image]

If anybody has idea how to get such format then let me know. And if there is no such format then I request to add this format.

I also want the reviews from other users that is it good idea as there are more than **1.5K** questions related to this and there are no lighlighting for badges names?